# PHP function that decides which HTML code to use?

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I'm looking for a function like and if else statement for php which will execute certain html code.

For example:

```
<?php>
$result = 1;

if ($result == 1)
<?>

html code



else

html code
```

So, based off the result variable gotten from php scripts, a certain html page is output. I've tried echoing the entire html page, but it just displays the html code-> tags and such.

Hopefully you get what I'm trying to get across, ask if you need any clarification questions. Thanks!

Comment: No, this question is not clear. (1) HTML code is not "executed," particularly not by PHP. (2) What's the problem with using if/else?

Comment: If what you are getting from your current echo'ing of the html is just tags take a look at you mimetype settings for your webserver. But, further clarification would make this an easier "question" to answer and understand.

Comment: I mean executed as in by on the same page. My .php runs code which evaluates something, and then has html underneath so that the browser can display it. The problem I'm facing with the if else statement, is in order to display the html, I have to exit php coding. Thus, the if else statement will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem I'm facing with the if else statement, is in order to display the html, I have to exit php coding. Thus, the if else statement will not work. ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567093/php-function-that-decides-which-html-code-to-use#comment15301625_11567093))

This is not entirely true. You can use the approach below:

```
<?php
// Do evaluations

if ( $result == "something" )
{
?>
    <p>Example HTML code</p>
<?php
} elseif ( $result == "another thing")
{
?>
    <span>Different HTML code</p>
<?php
} else {
?>
    <h4>Foobar.</h4>
<?php
}

// Rest of the PHP code
?>
```

Or, if you don't want to *exit PHP coding*, you can use the `echo` or `print` statements. Example:

```
<?php
// Evaluations

if ( $result == "foo" )
{
    echo "<p>Bar.</p>";
} else {
    echo "<h4>Baz</p>";
}

// Some else PHP code
?>
```

Just be careful with proper sequences of `'` and `"` characters. If your HTML tags are to have arguments, you should watch your step and use either of the following approaches:

```
echo "<span class=\"foo\">bar</span>";
echo '<span class="foo">bar</span>";
```

Answer (score 3):

That should work:

```
<?php
    $result = 1;
    if($result==1) {
?>
        html code
<?php
    } else {
?>
        html code
<?php
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to evaluate some PHP and print the HTML results later, you could use something like this

```
<?php
$output = "";
if ( $result == "something" ) {
    $output = '<p>Example HTML code</p>';
} else if ( $result == "another thing") {
    $output = '<span>Different HTML code</p>';
} else {
    $output = '<h4>Foobar.</h4>';
}

// Output wherever you like
echo $output;
?>
```

EDIT (because I'm not sure what you;re trying to do so i'm just putting out different ideas):

If you're trying to output an entire page, it may be useful to use `header('location: newPage.html');` instead of `$output`. This redirects the browser to an entirely new web page. Or you can likely `include newPage.html` as well.

Answer (score 0):

very close:

```
<?php
$result = 1;    
if ($result == 1){
?>    
html code    
<?php } //close if
else {
?>    
html code    
<?php
} //close else
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can echo html code something like this

```
<?php
$result = 1;
if ($result == 1){
echo "<h1>I love using PHP!</h1>";
}
?>
```

this would output if Result is 1

```
**I love using PHP!** //but slightly bigger since its H1
```